# Bounty counting toward 200 limit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Are bounty awards exempt from the 200 points/day reputation limit?**
>
> Yes, bounty awards are exempt from the daily reputation cap.—[Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Today (Sep-9) I awarded 100 bounty and they capped the daily limit at 100 + 2 accepted + 3 accepting, so today got capped at 136, shouldn't it be +136?

I.e. the theoretical ceiling should still be 236, right?

[image]

At 23:40 ... 10 points were not counted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the full accounting for September 9:

```
+145    23:40   15 events    Why does the Piper Cherokee (PA-28-140) engine have such low horsepower despite the very large displacement?
 +20    20:55   4 events     Why is “clearway minus stopway” used in V1 adjustments?
 +20    09:01   2 events     Why don't we fly helicopters with yokes?
 +15    12:18   accept  Do planes have odometers?
 +10    21:20   upvote  If planes can go faster, why don't airlines fly faster?
 +10    01:21   upvote  Could a plane with an electric turbine engine generate enough lift to get to space?
 +5     23:04   upvote  Why are offset lead-in arcs used?
 +2     15:53   accept  How can a non-IFR rated pilot fly SVFR?
 +2     15:49   accept  Are weather balloon launches NOTAM'ed?
 +2     15:42   accept  How close is an obstruction allowed to be in an instrument approach?
 +5/-50 15:58   2 events     Is there a time limit for a line-up and wait?
-50     23:08   bounty  Why does the spiraling slipstream from a propeller hit the left side of the fin?
```

By my calculations, you got a total of +236 from upvotes and accepts. You also spent 100 reputation on 2 bounties. However, those bounties do not increase the cap for that day. According to the [help center](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination of the activities below. [Bounty awards](/helpcenter/bounty), [accepted answers](/helpcenter/accepted-answer), and [association bonuses](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/) are not subject to the daily reputation limit.

Note that your reputation was reduced because you *offered* bounties.  When someone else awards a bounty for one of your answers, those aren't counted toward your daily limit. But you don't increase your daily limit by offering bounties.

On the other hand your two accepted answers and the +6 from accepting 3 answers do not count against the rep cap. So by 23:40 (when you got your final upvote) you'd hit the cap: 236 - 30 - 6 = 200.

Comment: Attached screenshot shows at 23:40 an omitted 10 points. So it should have been 146 (if that's the only omission). I'm reporting for the bug, not for the points :)

Comment: Ah. I see what you mean. It's still not a bug. The reputation from accepted and accepting answers doesn't count against cap. (I updated the answer.)